# Why didn't the Fifth Element help Mondoshawans to defend against Mangalore attack?

Tags: the-fifth-element

The Fifth Element is a "Supreme Warrior".

If so, why didn't she take up the defense of Mondoshawan ship against Mangalore attack?

Was that because she was in cryosleep at the moment? Or not "human-awakened" by sweet and sappy romantic feelings?

Comment: I seem to recall the remnants of her hand being on a control stick of sorts. I always got the impression that the Mangalore just surprised them with an ambush that they should have been better prepared for.

Comment: You've obviously seen it more recently than any of us have... you should probably know.

Comment: @phantom42  The hand was gripping the handle from the case.  When the Mangalores take the case (which turns out to be empty) to Zorg, you can see there's a chunk missing where one of the handles should be.

Comment: @Nerrolken Nice. My turn to have never noticed something.

Comment: @InguShama Actually [someone else](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/94882/what-was-the-deal-with-korbens-neighbor) just watched it last night :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### She wasn't awake...

The Fifth Element is, at most times, more of a statue than a living thing.  We see it that way in the opening scene, when the Mondoshawan pick it up in the 20th century.  This is also how it is illustrated in Cornelius's book, and that bronze-metal appearance is consistent with the hand that was recovered from the crash.

Given this, it's likely that if the Fifth Element was ever designed to "wake up" into a person like Leeloo, it was a rare occurrence and it hadn't happened by the time of the Mangalore attack.

### ...but she likely couldn't have helped anyway.

The Mangalore attack on the Mondoshawan ship was swift and brutal.  It took only a few strafing runs to crash the ship, and the Mondoshawan ship doesn't seem to have any weaponry at all.  At least, if it did, they didn't have time to use it.

Being a peaceful, seemingly harmless race, the Mondoshawan probably couldn't have put up much of a fight in a ship-to-ship battle, even if the Fifth Element had been in "Leeloo-form."

Answer (score 0):

Leeloo isn't a warrior, she's a supreme being who is also a weapon. She doesn't seem to display any skills that could have helped them in that battle, if she was already awakened. And she may have been since she did tell the whole story of the battle to Korben in the taxi, as if experienced.
However, other than strength and her accelerated learning rate her power is only as the weapon to fight evil.

As for the 'sappy romance activation' part yes, she needed that to fully equip because she spent her last time on the computer learning about the worst of human nature and then witnessing it on the ship where she was shot up and left for dead. She needed to see the light in the dark. Love is light and light conquers darkness.